# Customize 'Copy' text popup (UIWebView)?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to customize the user text selection behavior in a
UIWebView. Currently, when a user highlights a region of text in a
UIWebView the 'Copy' action sheet appears, allowing you to copy the
text. I would like to perform some custom action on text selection,
effectively replacing the 'Copy' dialog, or adding another option to
the list of options (e.g. 'Copy' |  'Search').

My question is: Is there any Apple-accepted way of doing this? I'd
prefer not to put my app approval in jeopardy, so doing this by the
book is ideal. I've seen similar questions asked about this topic, but
all remain unanswered. Can anyone provide some insight on how to
accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup you refer to is called a UIMenuController. You can access the `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController]` method to get the menu controller. You can then add your own `UIMenuItems` to the menu controller, and these can be shown contextually, using the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method on the UIWebView. For more info, refer to the [iOS Developer Reference on UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and is close to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it seems as if the only way to get this to work is to use this technique with a UIWebView subclass. Even though Apple tells developers not to use it, it's the only way to do this, AFAIK. Still curious if subclassing UIWebView is grounds for rejection.

Comment: Subclass ing UIWebView will not get you rejected, and should not cause issues if your subclass only overrides the canPerdormAction method and NOTHING else. Apple is worried about messing with the drawing of UIWebView, which is not recommended.